Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND using sf org login jwt and with proxy
I can login using salesforce jwt on my laptop with direct internet connection, no problem.
Here are the commands,
token=<omitted>
url=https://testing-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com
user=email@gmail.com
alias=any1
sf org login jwt -i $token -f server.key -o $user -r $url --json -a $alias --dev-debug

But when I started with the company server and with proxy, it started to have this errors below,
[20:15:55.746] DEBUG (sf:oclif:MyDomainResolver): Re-trying dns lookup again....
[20:15:56.750] DEBUG (sf:oclif:MyDomainResolver): Attempting to resolve url: testing-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com
[20:15:56.774] DEBUG (sf:oclif:MyDomainResolver): An error occurred trying to resolve: testing-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com
[20:15:56.774] DEBUG (sf:oclif:MyDomainResolver): Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND testing-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com
[20:15:56.774] DEBUG (sf:oclif:MyDomainResolver): Re-trying dns lookup again....
[20:15:57.775] DEBUG (sf:oclif:MyDomainResolver): Attempting to resolve url: testing-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com
[20:15:57.793] DEBUG (sf:oclif:MyDomainResolver): An error occurred trying to resolve: testing-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com
[20:15:57.793] DEBUG (sf:oclif:MyDomainResolver): Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND testing-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com
[20:15:57.793] DEBUG (sf:oclif:MyDomainResolver): Re-trying dns lookup again....

It will throw that errors for a long time until I break it with ctrl-c.
proxy settings:
no_proxy=.domain.com,localhost,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
https_proxy=http://test.corp.domain.com:8080
NO_PROXY=.domain.com,localhost,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
HTTPS_PROXY=http://test.corp.domain.com:8080
HTTP_PROXY=http://test.corp.domain.com:8080
http_proxy=http://test.corp.domain.com:8080

Testing of curl: all ok
$ curl testing-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com
$curl test.salesforce.com
$ curl login.salesforce.com

Please help, thanks!

I add these,
npm config set https-proxy http://test.corp.domain.com:8080
npm config set proxy http://test.corp.domain.com:8080
npm config set noproxy .domain.com,localhost,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
npm config set strict-ssl false.  Didn't seem to help.  My server proxy I can download any files from github or any.

Do you have node in your path? Could you try node -p 'require("dns").lookup("[your domain]", function(){console.dir(arguments)})' ? (I assume you didn't actually target "testing-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com", because I can neither resolve this.) What OS, by the way?

It's node:latest, debian.  I'm getting this on your node cli, "[Arguments] {
'0': Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND [salesforce.com]
at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:109:26) {
errno: -3008,
code: 'ENOTFOUND',
syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
hostname: '[salesforce.com]'
}
}"

I have the same error "errno: -3008, code: ENOTFOUND" on google cloud cli/vm/docker but sf org jwt login is working there.  On my laptop the node cli of yours a success "GetAddrInfoReqWrap {
callback: [Function (anonymous)],
family: 0,
hostname: '[salesforce.com]',
oncomplete: [Function: onlookup]
}
[Arguments] { '0': null, '1': '10.223.36.129', '2': 4 }
"

I setup again the proper proxy with a gateway server and a client.
# setup gateway -start
ens33 internal  -192.168.99.90
ens32 external  -192.168.133.90

## enable ip forwarding
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward # need to be inside root
sudo vi /etc/sysctl.conf
   net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
sudo sysctl -p

## configure network interfaces
#***let if be dhcp, this is a testing anyways, make sure internal have no gateway
#sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager

##Configure NAT (Network Address Translation)

sudo dnf install iptables-services
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ens32 -j MASQUERADE
sudo service iptables save
sudo iptables -L -t nat
sudo dnf install nftables
sudo systemctl enable --now nftables
sudo vi /etc/nftables.conf
table ip nat {
    chain postrouting {
        type nat hook postrouting priority 100; policy accept;
        oifname "ens32" masquerade
    }
}
sudo systemctl reload nftables

##Configure Clients
Set the gateway for client machines to the CentOS server's LAN IP (e.g., 192.168.99.90).
Configure DNS on clients (e.g., Google's 8.8.8.8 or a local DNS server).
nmcli connection modify ens32 ipv4.addresses 192.168.99.0/24
nmcli connection modify ens32 ipv4.gateway 192.168.99.90
nmcli connection modify ens32 ipv4.dns 8.8.8.8
nmcli connection modify ens32 ipv4.method auto
nmcli connection down ens32; nmcli connection up ens32

##Allow forwarding of packets between the LAN and WAN interfaces.
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=external --add-masquerade --permanent
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=internal --add-interface=ens33 --permanent
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=external --add-interface=ens32 --permanent
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=external --add-forward-port=port=80:proto=tcp:toport=80:toaddr=192.168.99.90 --permanent
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=internal --add-port=80/tcp
sudo firewall-cmd --reload

### check
sudo tcpdump -i ens33

# setup gateway -end

Now I'm getting the same error as my company proxy.
  https-proxy-agent:parse-proxy-response got proxy server response: 'HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established' +33ms
  https-proxy-agent:agent Upgrading socket connection to TLS +35ms
  https-proxy-agent:agent creating new HttpsProxyAgent instance: Url { protocol: 'http:', slashes: true, auth: null, host: '192.168.133.90:3128', port: '3128', hostname: '192.168.133.90', hash: null, search: null, query: null, pathname: '/', path: '/', href: 'http://192.168.133.90:3128/' } +91ms
  agent-base Resolving socket for 'https:' request: 'POST /services/oauth2/token' +127ms
  https-proxy-agent:agent Creating `net.Socket`: { protocol: 'http:', slashes: true, auth: null, host: '192.168.133.90', port: 3128, hostname: '192.168.133.90', hash: null, search: null, query: null, href: 'http://192.168.133.90:3128/' } +1ms
  https-proxy-agent:parse-proxy-response onclose had error false +93ms
  https-proxy-agent:parse-proxy-response got proxy server response: 'HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established' +31ms
  https-proxy-agent:agent Upgrading socket connection to TLS +31ms
  https-proxy-agent:parse-proxy-response onclose had error false +216ms
[17:29:16.795] TRACE (sf:oclif:MyDomainResolver): Created 'sf:oclif:MyDomainResolver' child logger instance
[17:29:16.795] TRACE (sf:oclif): Setup child 'sf:oclif:MyDomainResolver' logger instance
[17:29:16.795] TRACE (sf:oclif:PollingClient): Created 'sf:oclif:PollingClient' child logger instance
[17:29:16.795] TRACE (sf:oclif): Setup child 'sf:oclif:PollingClient' logger instance
[17:29:16.795] DEBUG (sf:oclif:MyDomainResolver): Attempting to resolve url: uniwinux-dev-ed.develop.my.salesforce.com
[17:29:36.821] DEBUG (sf:oclif:MyDomainResolver): An error occurred trying to resolve: uniwinux-dev-ed.develop.my.salesforce.com
[17:29:36.821] DEBUG (sf:oclif:MyDomainResolver): Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND uniwinux-dev-ed.develop.my.salesforce.com
[17:29:36.821] DEBUG (sf:oclif:MyDomainResolver): Re-trying dns lookup again....
[17:29:37.823] DEBUG (sf:oclif:MyDomainResolver): Attempting to resolve url: uniwinux-dev-ed.develop.my.salesforce.com
[17:29:57.844] DEBUG (sf:oclif:MyDomainResolver): An error occurred trying to resolve: uniwinux-dev-ed.develop.my.salesforce.com
[17:29:57.844] DEBUG (sf:oclif:MyDomainResolver): Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND uniwinux-dev-ed.develop.my.salesforce.com
[17:29:57.844] DEBUG (sf:oclif:MyDomainResolver): Re-trying dns lookup again....
[17:29:58.846] DEBUG (sf:oclif:MyDomainResolver): Attempting to resolve url: uniwinux-dev-ed.develop.my.salesforce.com
[17:30:18.871] DEBUG (sf:oclif:MyDomainResolver): An error occurred trying to resolve: uniwinux-dev-ed.develop.my.salesforce.com
[17:30:18.871] DEBUG (sf:oclif:MyDomainResolver): Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND uniwinux-dev-ed.develop.my.salesforce.com
[17:30:18.871] DEBUG (sf:oclif:MyDomainResolver): Re-trying dns lookup again....


[17:33:28.114] DEBUG (sf:oclif:MyDomainResolver): An error occurred trying to resolve: uniwinux-dev-ed.develop.my.salesforce.com
[17:33:28.114] DEBUG (sf:oclif:MyDomainResolver): Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND uniwinux-dev-ed.develop.my.salesforce.com
[17:33:28.114] DEBUG (sf:oclif:MyDomainResolver): Re-trying dns lookup again....
  sf:telemetry Spawning "/usr/bin/node /usr/lib/node_modules/@salesforce/cli/node_modules/@salesforce/plugin-telemetry/processes/upload.js /home/ric/.cache/sf /tmp/sf-telemetry/telemetry-124e0a4800cfd536eaab1919988cf6dcd9b0d9ab.log" +4m

The testing are all the same with this and my company proxy,
[ric@client1 ~]$ curl salesforce.com
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: salesforce.com
[ric@client1 ~]$
export http_proxy=http://192.168.133.90:3128
export https_proxy=http://192.168.133.90:3128
[ric@client1 ~]$ curl salesforce.com
[ric@client1 ~]$ curl -O https://developer.salesforce.com/media/salesforce-cli/sf/channels/stable/sf-linux-x64.tar.xz
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 34.4M  100 34.4M    0     0  53.9M      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 53.9M
[ric@client1 ~]$


To be honest, if node can't resolve salesforce.com on your box, this is hardly a Salesforce question and you should move it to stackoverflow.com. At least, if I may ask you, could you add the above to your question (if you think that's helpful in order for someone to come up with an answer) rather than posting this as an answer? Or is this somehow meant to answer your question?

I'm getting this on the /var/log/messages, Dec 16 21:30:46 centos9 named[1588]: client @0x7f086c01c7f8 192.168.99.91#56140 (uniwinux-dev-ed.develop.my.salesforce.com.localdomain): query (cache) 'uniwinux-dev-ed.develop.my.salesforce.com.localdomain/A/IN' denied

I got it, I have to redo the solutions for I have so many, I'll paste later.  Thanks!

On your dns/bind, make sure you have these --- listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; any; }; listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; any; }; allow-query { localhost; any; }; recursion yes; --- Make sure you have gateway server with external (internet)and internal (no internet, no gateway ip) network and you client is on the internal (don't test with one interface only, you will always have internet even if you configure squid proxy).  Before you add listen any, test first to fail.  You have to port forward the 80/443/53 from both iptables and firewall, I use centos9, u'll have to configure static ip with nmcli.

You'll have to add the proxy on the client --- export http_proxy=http://192.168.99.90:3129
export https_proxy=http://192.168.99.90:3129
export no_proxy="localhost,127.0.0.1,localaddress,localdomain.com" ---.  The npm proxy, is not needed unless you need npm install or sf update.

When it's failing, the squid log is not enough, you should check also the DNS - /var/log/messages for error like --- client host denied AAAA IN DNS.

Instead of putting allow-query any (or localnets).  You can do this ---export SF_DISABLE_DNS_CHECK=true
npm config set dns 192.168.99.90.
